# javax.ws.rs.core Response combine with Spring Boot anotations return everything in json response?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jersey

My code works this way but is there any way to combine Response method witch l need in this case with Spring boot anotations without returning whole response data back?
l guess that RestController with PostMapping include Response return everything.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class Resource {

@PostMapping(value = "/post")
public Response post(@RequestBody final Data data) {
    Response response = null;
    try {
        validateData(data);
        LOG.info("SUCCESS");
        response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity("Success").build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());

        response = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
    return response;
}


{
"context": {
    "headers": {},
    "entity": "Success",
    "entityType": "java.lang.String",
    "entityAnnotations": [],
    "entityStream": {
        "committed": false,
        "closed": false
    },
    "stringHeaders": {},
    "mediaType": null,
    "allowedMethods": [],
    "committed": false,
    "entityTag": null,
    "links": [],
    "acceptableMediaTypes": [
        {
            "type": "*",
            "subtype": "*",
            "parameters": {},
            "quality": 1000,
            "wildcardType": true,
            "wildcardSubtype": true
        }
    ],
    "acceptableLanguages": [
        "*"
    ],
    "entityClass": "java.lang.String",
    "requestCookies": {},
    "responseCookies": {},
    "lengthLong": -1,
    "lastModified": null,
    "date": null,
    "length": -1,
    "language": null,
    "location": null
},
"status": 200,
"stringHeaders": {},
"statusInfo": "OK",
"mediaType": null,
"metadata": {},
"allowedMethods": [],
"cookies": {},
"entityTag": null,
"links": [],
"lastModified": null,
"entity": "Success",
"date": null,
"length": -1,
"language": null,
"location": null,
"headers": {}
}
```

If l use Jersey anotations with same code l get what l need. Response in body with my data, also l cannot use Swagger2 because doesn't support Jersey.
Is there some way to use first part with spring boot anotations without returning everything in Response method, just status code 200 or 400?
Method need to be Response not Data or List, Thanks

```
@Component
@Path("/v1")
public class Resource {

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response post(@RequestBody final Data data) {
        Response response = null;
        try {
            validateData(data);
            LOG.info("SUCCESS");
            response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new BasicResponse("0", "Success")).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());

            response = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(new BasicResponse(Status.BAD_REQUEST.toString(), e.getMessage())).build();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used Jersey for Rest Api and I dont know where you get that json. Doing curl to thoses api I just got a normal response. You should see your BasicResponse object as json, only that.

Comment: @WilderValera l got normal response as well with Jersey annotations, but l need with Spring Boot annotations with Response method (first part of code)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should return`ResponseEntity` instead of `Response`, Spring uses `ResponseEntity` instead, `Response` is a Jax-RS type so I doubt it will work properly with Spring annotations,  in your case:

`return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");`

should work.

Comment: If your remote client is expecting a Response type then how will that work?

Comment: not sure I understand the question. `Response` or `ResponseEntity` is just a wrapper of your actual response, you define the payload.

Comment: Sorry. I should have provided more information. I have a restful client and server. Both use JAX-RS.  I switched the server from Apache CXF to SpringBoot and now the server throws an exception trying to return a RESPONSE type even though the code compiles.  All that has changed are the annotations and the underlying implementation.  I expected that the switching to SpringBoot implementation of JAX-RS would not matter.

Comment: I switched to ResponseEntity and it does work.  Not sure why, though.  Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelStarkie it works because what goes over the wire between your server and client is just text - the HTTP protocol is handled by the library you use, it's not like you're passing a Java object across the network. Hence why you can communicate happily between servers and clients written in any programming language.